# how can i split a address string into street and housenumber through SQL in an Visual FoxPro database

Tags: sql, vb.net, visual-foxpro

our customer uses a Visual FoxPro database.
I need to create a sql string where I have to split the address field into the street and the housenumber.
I found the AT and CharIndex functions, but they only work directly in Visual Fox Pro, not in an SQL statement.

I use vb.net to connect to the VFP database through oledb.
It has to be done in the sql statement, can't use further code for it.

Thanks in advance.

```
Dim con As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection = Nothing
    con = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=vfpoledb;Data Source=" & Me.lblDatabase.Text & ";Collating Sequence=machine;")
    con.Open()

    Dim sqlString As String = "SELECT Address FROM AddressTable"
    Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(sqlString, con)
    Try
        con.Open()
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try


    Dim myDA As OleDbDataAdapter = New OleDbDataAdapter(cmd)

    Dim myDataSet As DataSet = New DataSet()

    ' Using DataAdapter object fill data from database into DataSet object
    Try
        myDA.Fill(myDataSet, "MyTable")
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("Error " & Err.Description)
    End Try


    ' Binding DataSet to DataGridView
    Try
        DataGridView1.DataSource = myDataSet.Tables("MyTable").DefaultView
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try


    con.Close()
```

Comment: Is there any consistency to the addresses, i.e. are they *always*, without exception, in the format "123 The Street", or maybe "123, The Street"? Could there be a "221b Baker St", or a "Dunroamin"?

Comment: You can of course use AT() in an SQL executed against VFP data through VFPOLEDB. Here the real question is, what does your data look like, and what you think you would be doing with AT()? And also, why should it be done in SQL?

Comment: Adresses here in the Netherlands have always: streetname {space} number, so I need to find the space in the field. Thanks, maybe I've done something wrong before, AT seems to work now.  sqlstring = "SELECT left(adm_prf2.st_street, AT(" ", adm_prf2.st_street)) FROM adm_prf2" Works now

Comment: @SanderWijnen, Please see my reply. While your code may work, you are likely to lose data.

Answer (score 0):

You are saying it is constantly separated at the first space. Then:

```
Dim constr As String = "Provider=vfpoledb;Data Source=" & Me.lblDatabase.Text
Dim sqlString As String = "SELECT Address, 
    cast(Substr(Address, 1, AT(' ', Address)) as char(100)) as StreetName,
    cast(Ltrim(Substr(Address, AT(' ', Address))) as char(100)) as AddressLineRest
    FROM AddressTable"

Dim myDataTable As DataTable = New DataTable()
Dim myDA As OleDbDataAdapter = New OleDbDataAdapter(sqlString, constr)

' Using DataAdapter object fill data from database into DataSet object

Try
    myDA.Fill(myDataTable)
    DataGridView1.DataSource = myDataTable.DefaultView
Catch ex As Exception
    MsgBox("Error " & Err.Description)
End Try
```

PS: Probably instead of MsgBox you would want to use standard .Net MessageBox.

NOTE: It is important to cast your data to a known data type (like Char(100) here). Otherwise you could silently lose data.